# ClosedXml C# Overwriting existing style of excel file when new data are inserted for a range

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am trying to insert new data, but whenever I put new data then existing styles of my template are overwritten making them default ones. The background style of cells is replaced to default white color.

```
public IWorkbookBuilderSheetOperation Insert<T>(IEnumerable<T[]> rows, int firstCellRow, int firstCellColumn)
{
    _currentSheet.IsSelected();

    var lastCell = CalculateLastCell(rows, firstCellRow, firstCellColumn);
    var range = _currentSheet!.Range(firstCellRow, firstCellColumn, lastCell.lastCellRow, lastCell.lastCellColumn);
    _ = range.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(rows);

    return this;
}
```

How can I keep existing styles when I read a template file and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an Excel table, it will keep a uniform look no matter how many rows you insert using the methods on `IXLTable`.
If you can't use a table and you need to keep using `cell.InsertData()`, then you could still manually copy the `.Style` of the old range to where you want it.